# Music files extensions in Finder search are missing, cannot rename

Tags: mp3, finder, rename, osx-el-capitan

I have a problem with all my music files with `mp3` extension.

I had Mac OS X Snow Leopard and I made backup of all my files to hard drive and changed the internal hard drive to new SSD with fresh copy of El Capitan. After this operation I took all my files from the backup (video, music, jpg…) to my new SSD drive and everything was OK until I made a search in the Finder.

When I made a search for music file I could see only the title of the song without the `mp3` extension. I can't change or rename any files in the Finder search.

I can rename and see the entire filename only if I get inside the folder where the files are.

I have indexed all the hard drive in the Spotlight few times and it's always the same problem. This happens only with `mp3` extension. No problem with `mp4`, `jpg`, `pdf`…

I'm lost. Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

### Music titles in Finder search windows with El Capitan

The music title in Finder search windows is a new feature in El Capitan. Finder's search windows display the title of a music file instead of its file name if the music file has a title. As you've noticed, El Capitan's Finder won't let you change the title. Finder displays the path and file name at the bottom of the window when a title is selected. Nothing has happened to the file extension, which is still with the file name, but the extension is not part of the title.

[image: Finder search window]

There are ways to change the name of the file.

1. Select a title in the Finder search window, and right-click to Get Info, or type CMD-I. Change the file name in the Name & Extension section of the Info window.
2. Open the folder with the file and change the file name. You found this method.

There doesn't appear to be a way to turn off or disable this new El Capitan feature.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer it still seems to me as a bug because i have 450 Gb of mp3 files that i can't change unless i'm getting inside the folder.
if you looking for a name like "frozen" and you got 8 singers different you need to touch every file to see who is the singer or group very strange.
by the way when i index the spotlight from beginning this option is coming back and after the index is finish the option is locked again.
very strange